# understanding the gradient of a curve through derivative

Tags: derivatives, gradient-flows

Let's say I have a curve of the form $$y = x^2$$

therefore the gradient is $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2x$$

**My question is :**

does this mean that the value of the gradient at $x = 3$ is $6$
or the change of $x$ by $3$ would give the value of the gradient as $6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning here is that if you change $x$ by a tiny amount $h$ from the point $x=3$ to $x=3+h$, then the value of $y$ changes by $6h$. Go ahead and try it out for $h=0.1,0.01,0.001$. You will see why $h$ has to be small. The smaller $h$ is , the closer $\frac{\Delta y}{h}$ will be to the value 6.

At another point, say $x=4$, you find that changing $x$ from 4 to $4+h$ results in a change in $y$ of about $8h$. The scaling factor (6 or 8 etc) is what the derivative (gradient) gives you.

Comment: the reason why i asked this question, was because, i needed to understand https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5075/what-is-the-proof-behind-the-gradient-of-a-curve-being-equal-proportional-to-the, can you help me with this formula?

Comment: can you also add a proof that if y will change from 3 to 3+h y will change by 6h?

Comment: @souparnomajumder Did you test out with those 3 values of h that I mentioned? Your question had to do with the intuition behind what the derivative means.  As to why that change, just look at the defjntion of the derivative. $y’=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{y(x+h)-y(x)}{h}$ from which you immediately get the idea of why for small h, $y(x+h)-y(x)= h \times y’(x)$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the derivative of a function is the rate of change of a function, say $f(x)$. It defines the gradient of the tangent at a specific point $x$. For a parabola, we visualise that the gradient is always changing, so the derivative of a parabola, say, $f(x)=x^2$ would be $f'(x)=2x$. The gradient of $f(x)$ at any point $x$ is $2x$.

So in summary, the derivative gives the gradient at point $x$.